# Cannot use ternary operator in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I can't figure out why I get a `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error if I use a ternary operator in my LINQ query.

```
var courses = from d in somesource
                          orderby d.SourceName, d.SourceType
                          select new
                          {
                              ID = d.InternalCode,
                              Name = string.Format("{0} - {1}{2}", d.InternalCode, d.SourceName, (d.SourceType.Length > 0 ? ", " + d.SourceType : string.Empty))
                          };
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`d.SourceType` is `null`.

You should call

```
(String.IsNullOrEmpty(d.SourceType) ? ", " + d.SourceType : string.Empty)
```

Comment: You are correct.  It turns out that even though it's a string it comes back null if empty.  Thanks.  I will select you as the correct answer once it allows me.  I've upvoted similar answers.

Answer (score 1):

You're checking the `Length` property of `SourceType`, which could be null.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe SourceType is null, so you get exception on d.SourceType.Length.